# What is classified as a physical attack vs. a special attack?

Tags: live-a-live-remake

In Live-a-Live (2022 remake) there are a lot of different attacks, and they can be classified in a lot of different ways (different "elements", ranges, etc). In the game there are 3 stats that represent attack: Attack, Physical Attack, and Special Attack.

Each character has a fair amount of diversity in their attacks, so it doesn't seem simple to say "this character is entirely physical" but at the same time, it's challenging to determine what attacks are special and what aren't, as it's not listed anywhere. So how can you tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/livealive/comments/w95fmh/special_vs_physical/):

> In-game the quickest way to learn is to play Masaru and Akira as they both are polar opposites of each other in terms of growth and abilities, **Masaru being entirely physical** and having the full repertoire save the slashes and arrow. Whereas **Akira has the full display of special attacks**, except the two physical ones he starts with.

> Star, Skull, Elements, and Atom symbols are all special.
> Fist, Kick, Slash, Arrow, Rope Lasso, Jumping icon, and the Mallet are considered physical.
> Earth based attacks are an exception with Masaru's being Vitality physical based and Oboro's being IQ based.

So, looking at [Masaru's moveset](https://www.ign.com/wikis/live-a-live/Characters#Masaru), these types are considered physical attacks:

- Punch
- Agile
- Martial
- Grapple

On the other hand, looking at [Akira's moveset](https://www.ign.com/wikis/live-a-live/Characters#Akira), these types are considered special attacks:

- Spirit
- Divine
- Demonic
- Fire
- Ice

With regard to their actual calculations it's better to check [the wiki](https://live-a-live.fandom.com/wiki/Characters) because attacks can be hybrids in terms of calculations, e.g. mix of Special Attack (SpA) and Speed (Spe), like Shifu's ultimate skill.

Bear in mind that when the wiki refers to IQ that means Special attack.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a ton!

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)